# Difference between identifier and expression in Go

Tags: go

http://golang.org/ref/spec#RangeClause

```
RangeClause = ( ExpressionList "=" | IdentifierList ":=" ) "range" Expression .
```

Trying to understand the range clause and specifically the difference between an [identifier](http://golang.org/ref/spec#identifier) and an [expression](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Expression)

Thanks.

Comment: They're not the same thing in Go as they are in any other programming language?  [Identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identifier#In_computer_languages), [Expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_(computer_science))

Comment: @RobertHarvey They are. I think OP wants to know why there can be a expression list. Not sure though.

Comment: added the focus of my question. I want to understand why range differentiates them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the `range` keyword you can iterate over many things and assign the results while doing so.
You can assign to two things:

- Identifiers (via `IdentifierList`)
- Expressions (via `ExpressionList`)

#### Identifiers

These are new variables for use in the inner loop. They must obey the rules for identifiers (unicode names, no whitespaces, etc.). If you use these you have to use the `:=` operator between the list an the `range` keyword.

Example:

```
for i := range []int{1,2,3} {
    fmt.Println(i)
}
```

#### Expressions

You don't necessarily need to declare new variables, you can use existing ones and even
have expressions evaluated which return the storage location. A few examples:

Assign to a pointer ([Play](http://play.golang.org/p/9X70XVWdv4)):

```
var i = 0

func main() {
    p := &i

    for *p = range []int{1,2,3} {
        fmt.Println(i)
    }
}
```

Return a pointer and assign it ([Play](http://play.golang.org/p/WQ-0pft51r)):

```
var i = 0

func foo() *int {
    return &i
}

func main() {
    for *foo() = range []int{1,2,3} {
        fmt.Println(i)
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for clear answer and using "Play" phrasing to link to examples.